# Change currency showed in reports - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, currency, reports

Hi all Magento Wizards,

I have a question regarding the currency shown in reports. I have a Magento webshop where my base currency is Euro. I have multiple websites and store views, which have different currencies.

When I generate a report it always shows DKK in front of the totals, but really the totals are in Euro. This is very confusing and frustrating. My questin is actually very simple: where do I set the currency that is shown when generating reports?

[image: Example Report]

(Please see images for visualization of the problem)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 seem to use the currency for the **Website** that is set as **Default**.

To change which **Website** is **Default** go to **Store -> All Stores**.

Click a **Website** and check the **Set as Default** checkbox then save.

Now the report should be shown in the currency that is set for your Default Website.

PS. Note that you have two different types of [currency setup](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/currency-configuration.html). This could have an impact on the currency shown in reports. I have only tested with the **Website** scope for base currecy.